# Is it safe to emmit event after route push

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, event-bus

I have a button that should redirect user from one page to another:

```
this.$router.push('/my-profile/messages');
this.$nextTick(() =>
    this.$eventBus.$emit('passUserToMessages', user)
);
```

Then on the messages page i'm listening for this event:

```
this.$eventBus.$on('passUserToMessages', (user) => {
    this.usersToChatWith.push(user);
});
```

Can this guarantee that the page will always load data return block first then my event to populate the list

Comment: You should put your user in a [Vuex store](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) if you have to access it from a non-child component.

Answer (score 0):

If `$router.push` is an async operation then no, you cannot guarantee that, if the route loads something and you want to emit this event only after the loading is finished successfully then ideal place to emit the event will be that place.